# how to binding exchange to exchange for Rabbitmq in spring via xml

Tags: spring, rabbitmq

I know how to binding queues to exchange in spring like this:

```
 <!-- exchange queue binging key -->
     <rabbit:direct-exchange name="skyrim-mq-exchange"
         durable="true" auto-delete="false" id="skyrim-mq-exchange">
         <rabbit:bindings>
             <rabbit:binding queue="skyrim_queue_one" key="skyrim_queue_one" />
             <rabbit:binding queue="skyrim_queue_two" key="skyrim_queue_two" />
         </rabbit:bindings>
     </rabbit:direct-exchange>
```

But I can't find some useful demo about Exchange to Exchange bindings via xml.So I really want to know how to config in spring Xml ? Thanks in advance

Comment: I used to bind queues to exchanges. But then I took an arrow to the knee. Now I bind exchanges to exchanges

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!-- exchange for bd -->
<rabbit:fanout-exchange id="bd_exchange" name="bd_exchange" durable="true" auto-delete="false" >
    <rabbit:bindings>
        <rabbit:binding exchange="bd_0" />
    </rabbit:bindings>
</rabbit:fanout-exchange>

<rabbit:topic-exchange id="bd_0" name="bd_0" durable="true" auto-delete="false" >
    <rabbit:bindings>          
        <rabbit:binding queue="bd_restaurant" pattern="bd.*" />
    </rabbit:bindings>
</rabbit:topic-exchange>
```